# Problem with Application DB Context error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have this problem. How can I fix it?

I have been struggling for months with this problem and have no way of solving it.

```
public static class SeedData
{

    public static void EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = app.ApplicationServices
              .GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        if (!context.Products.Any())
        {
            context.Products.AddRange(
                new Product
                {
                    Name = "Kayak",
                    Description = "A boat for one person",
                    Category = "Watersports",
                    Price = 275
                },
               ...
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you "struggle for months" with it .... you should be at least be able to provide what you struggle with descriptively. Your code does not really do anything for us - it can not be run as is, to reproduce whatever problem you are facing. It is not a [mre] -you do not describe what effs you about it or what errors it produces. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question in a way that makes it answerable.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
public static void EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
    {
        var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        if (!context.Products.Any())
        {
            context.Products.AddRange(new Product
            {
                 Name = "Kayak",
                 Description = "A boat for one person",
                 Category = "Watersports",
                 Price = 275
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.